# RecyclerView setting text

Tags: android, list, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have just jumped to android with a very limited knowledge about recyclerview. I have used a a bit, but faced a situation where setting a text inside onBindViewHolder.Please bear with me.Check the following codes:

1.This is the json, here:

```
[
  {
    "restaurantSubscriptionType_Id": 1,
    "noOfDaysPlan": "1 Day Trial Meal",
    "restaurantSubscriptionEntity": [
      {
        "restaurantSubscriptionId": 39,
        "subscriptionPlan": "Breakfast & Lunch",
        "subscriptionImagePath": null,
        "subscriptionDays": 1,
        "subscriptionAmount": 150,
        "restaurant_Subscription_Type_Id": 1
      }
    ],
    "restaurantId": 224
  },
  {
    "restaurantSubscriptionType_Id": 2,
    "noOfDaysPlan": "5 Days Weekly Plan",
    "restaurantSubscriptionEntity": [
      {
        "restaurantSubscriptionId": 40,
        "subscriptionPlan": "Breakfast & Lunch",
        "subscriptionImagePath": null,
        "subscriptionDays": 5,
        "subscriptionAmount": 650,
        "restaurant_Subscription_Type_Id": 2
      },
      {
        "restaurantSubscriptionId": 41,
        "subscriptionPlan": "Only Lunch",
        "subscriptionImagePath": null,
        "subscriptionDays": 5,
        "subscriptionAmount": 500,
        "restaurant_Subscription_Type_Id": 2
      }
    ],
    "restaurantId": 224
  }
]
```

I have pojo2schema site

2.RestaurantSubscriptionEntity

```
public class RestaurantSubscriptionEntity {
private Integer restaurantSubscriptionId;
private String subscriptionPlan;
private String subscriptionImagePath;
private Integer subscriptionDays;
private Long subscriptionAmount;
private Integer restaurantSubscriptionTypeId;

public RestaurantSubscriptionEntity(){

}

public Integer getRestaurantSubscriptionId() {
    return restaurantSubscriptionId;
}

public void setRestaurantSubscriptionId(Integer restaurantSubscriptionId) {
    this.restaurantSubscriptionId = restaurantSubscriptionId;
}

public String getSubscriptionPlan() {
    return subscriptionPlan;
}

public void setSubscriptionPlan(String subscriptionPlan) {
    this.subscriptionPlan = subscriptionPlan;
}

public String getSubscriptionImagePath() {
    return subscriptionImagePath;
}

public void setSubscriptionImagePath(String subscriptionImagePath) {
    this.subscriptionImagePath = subscriptionImagePath;
}

public Integer getSubscriptionDays() {
    return subscriptionDays;
}

public void setSubscriptionDays(Integer subscriptionDays) {
    this.subscriptionDays = subscriptionDays;
}

public Long getSubscriptionAmount() {
    return subscriptionAmount;
}

public void setSubscriptionAmount(Long subscriptionAmount) {
    this.subscriptionAmount = subscriptionAmount;
}

public Integer getRestaurantSubscriptionTypeId() {
    return restaurantSubscriptionTypeId;
}

public void setRestaurantSubscriptionTypeId(Integer restaurantSubscriptionTypeId) {
    this.restaurantSubscriptionTypeId = restaurantSubscriptionTypeId;
}
```

3.DemoItemAll:

```
public class DemoItemAll {


private Integer restaurantSubscriptionTypeId;
private String noOfDaysPlan;

private List<RestaurantSubscriptionEntity> restaurantSubscriptionEntity = new ArrayList<RestaurantSubscriptionEntity>();

private Long restaurantId;

public DemoItemAll(){

}

public Integer getRestaurantSubscriptionTypeId() {
    return restaurantSubscriptionTypeId;
}

public void setRestaurantSubscriptionTypeId(Integer restaurantSubscriptionTypeId) {
    this.restaurantSubscriptionTypeId = restaurantSubscriptionTypeId;
}

public String getNoOfDaysPlan() {
    return noOfDaysPlan;
}

public void setNoOfDaysPlan(String noOfDaysPlan) {
    this.noOfDaysPlan = noOfDaysPlan;
}

public List<RestaurantSubscriptionEntity> getRestaurantSubscriptionEntity() {
    return restaurantSubscriptionEntity;
}

public void setRestaurantSubscriptionEntity(List<RestaurantSubscriptionEntity> restaurantSubscriptionEntity) {
    this.restaurantSubscriptionEntity = restaurantSubscriptionEntity;
}

public Long getRestaurantId() {
    return restaurantId;
}

public void setRestaurantId(Long restaurantId) {
    this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
}
```

4.Here my class which extends RecyclerView

```
    public class DemoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DemoAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<DemoItemAll> demoItemAllArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView title_tv,price_tv;
        private Button drop_down_button;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.day_plan_demo_tv_id);
            price_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_demo_tv_id);
            drop_down_button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.demo_drop_down_btn_id);



        }
    }


    public DemoAdapter(List<DemoItemAll> demoItemAllArrayList) {
        this.demoItemAllArrayList = demoItemAllArrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.demo_adapter, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        DemoItemAll demoItemAll=new DemoItemAll();

        //noOfDays
        holder.title_tv.setText(demoItemAll.getNoOfDaysPlan());

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return demoItemAllArrayList.size();

    }
}
```

now here inside onBindView,I need to set this but "subscriptionAmount"
belongs to RestaurantSubscriptionEntity class.How do I access it

`holder.price_tv.setText` //subscriptionAmount.

Comment: First of all this is *not* the `RecyclerView` issue. This is a design issue, I see you've got demoItemAllArrayList of `DemoItemAll` in your `Adapter` which in turn contains a list for `RestaurantSubscriptionEntity`. The question is do you want a list of `DemoItemAll`, `RestaurantSubscriptionEntity` or both of them. Please explain! Also reread your question and try and be brief and generic as possible.

Comment: Yes I do want a list of RestaurantSubscriptionEntity where I want access its field

Comment: Then why do you have `List<DemoItemAll> demoItemAllArrayList` in your adapter? Why not simply pass the adapter the actual list of `RestaurantSubscriptionEntity` items.

Comment: Just to clarify. You have mapped the JSON Objects to a List of 'RestaurantSubscriptionEntity' ? Then pass the List to the Adapter and access the Information you need like 'list.get(position).getInformation()'

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    DemoItemAll demoItemAll = demoItemAllArrayList.get(position);
    List<RestaurantSubscriptionEntity> entity = demoItemAll.getRestaurantSubscriptionEntity();

    holder.title_tv.setText(demoItemAll.getNoOfDaysPlan());
    holder.price_tv.setText(String.valueOf(entity.getSubscriptionAmount()))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just create new empty DemoItemAll object.

You need to use

`DemoItemAll demoItemAll = demoItemAllArrayList.get(position);`

instead of

`DemoItemAll demoItemAll = new DemoItemAll();`